# shiny renderUI resets unnecessarily with NavBar change

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, navbar

I am using a combination of NavBar page and Dashboard so that I can have a sidebar as well as different navbar tabs. I have a renderUI that changes based on which tab you are on.

I noticed that my renderUI does not stay constant as you switch among the navabs. This problem only occurs when the renderUi is dependent on the tab selected.

Can this be fixed?? I would like the input selected while someone is on Tab2 to stay selected if they go to Tab3.

See my minimum example here:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput("filter1","Filter1",c("a","b","c")),
    uiOutput("test")),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidPage(
      navbarPage(
    header="",title=NULL,id="navbar" ,collapsible = TRUE,fluid = TRUE,inverse = TRUE,
        tabPanel("Tab1",
             box(width=12,
                 h3("hello world"))),
        tabPanel("Tab2",
             box(width = 12,
                 h3(textOutput("txt")))),
        tabPanel("Tab3",
             box(width = 12,
                 h3(textOutput("txt2"))))
  ))))

server <- function(input, output,session){
  output$test<-renderUI({
    if (input$navbar == "Tab1"){

    }else{
      selectInput("test","Test",c("a","b","c"))
    }
  })

  output$txt<-renderText({
    paste0("You selected: ",as.character(input$test))
  })

  output$txt2<-renderText({
    paste0("You selected: ",as.character(input$test))
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Also, I know that I could make conditional sidebar, but in my real app I have a ton of stuff in the sidebar and I really don't want to completely duplicate it... There must be a better  way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `conditionalPanel` rather than `renderUI`. Replace `uiOutput("test")` with the following code.

```
conditionalPanel(
  "input.navbar != 'Tab1'",
  selectInput("test","Test",c("a","b","c"))
)
```

#### Edit

If you want `filter1` to disappear as well, add it to the conditionalpanel like so.

```
conditionalPanel(
  "input.navbar != 'Tab1'",
  selectInput("filter1", "Filter1", c("a", "b", "c")),
  selectInput("test", "Test", c("a", "b", "c"))
)
```

Comment: Wow, I just realized I fundamentally didn't understand condtionalPanel until just now. Thank you so much! This is a game changer.

Comment: Would it be possible for filter1 to dissappear while on tab1? That's what I was hoping for @Gregor de Cillia

Comment: I just edited my answer. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Actually, what you had before was working for me! At somepoint I changed input.navbar to input$navbar and it broke. My fault, not yours.